# How to detect app is removed from recents (Overview screen) on Android Oreo?

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo, android-recents, android-8.1-oreo

Until now (before Android Oreo) I was handling removing from app recents via `Service.onTaskRemoved()`, like:

```
public class OnAppRemovedFromRecentListener extends Service {

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
        // there I am handling removing from recents
    }
}
```

but now when I run app on Android Oreo I'am unable to achieve the same behaviour in any way. Tried 2 approaches:

1. If still using `Service` then service is desroyed after some time of inactivity when app is in background and then if user removes app from recents `onTaskRemoved` is not called.
2. If switching from `Service` to `JobIntentService` and starting this service via `JobIntentServiceLauncher.enqueueWork` then almost immediately the OnAppRemovedFromRecentListener is destroyed and `onTaskRemoved` is also not called when app is removed from recents

Does anybody know way how to detect removing my app from recents on Android Oreo which will work always?

Comment: hi did you find any solution

Comment: Unfortunately not. Notification about your answer was light in the tunnel for me - I thought that somebody found solution :P

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution?

Comment: Any Solutions??

Answer (score 0):

If you use a activity , i think you can use onDestroy() or onStop() methods to detect cleanup or closing of app properly

Comment: I want to handle it also beyond the activity - for example when exited from app by back button, then all activities are destroyed but process still works and is available on 'recents'. So relaying on activity onDestrop and onStop is not enough :(